# Changing button text by Click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm using following codes in a JSP page.This is my function to change button text by a button click in JavaScript.

```
    <script>
    function click(){
        var el=document.getElementById(btnaccept);
        if(el.value=="Accept"){
           el.value==="Accepted"; 
        }else{
            el.value==="Accept";
        }
    } 
 </script>
```

This is my button;

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnaccept"  onclick="click()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" name="accept"></span> Accept
      </button>
```

This code is not functioning when I click the "Accept" button. What error I have done here?

Comment: `===` does a comparison. You want  `=`, which assigns a new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
<script>
      function click1() {
        var el = document.getElementById('btnaccept');
        //alert(el.innerHTML);
        if (el.textContent == "Accept") {
          el.textContent = "Accepted";
        } else {
          el.textContent = "Accept";
        }
      }
    </script>
```

change onclick event to `click1()`

Comment: Dont compare with value, instead textContent or innerhtml u can use

Comment: `innerHTML` will give the whole inner html inside the button : here in this case it will be `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" name="accept"></span> Accept` . Only use `textContent`.

Comment: @Rohit, correct, but that will be a useful info for the OP

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- Don't name your funtion `click` that won't work.
- You are not using value on the button, you are using inner HTML.
- use  if you want to manipulate the value, or manipulate ineerHTML if you want the other way around.
- `document.getElementById` takes string as argument, so you want to write there `document.getElementById('btnaccept');`
- Use `=` to assign value `===` is comparison (equal value or type)

<kbd>[See working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmpqxgo/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should use `click` as function name use any other name.
It will treat it as mouseevent [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

`===` is used for comparison to assign value use `=`.

Here I have used `clickbutton()` instead of `click()` for the function name.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="btnaccept"  onclick="clickbutton()">
```

**Script**

```js
function clickbutton() {
   var el = document.getElementById('btnaccept');
   if (el.value == "Accept") {
     el.value = "Accepted";
   } else {
     el.value = "Accept";
   }
 }
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/7hu2pb53/2/)

Comment: var el=document.getElementById(btnaccept) is wrong,

Comment: I guess the down vote was because you didn't use quotes for getting the element in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mattt said, you need to use the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `===` when assigning values. Also, when using `getElementById`, it will be expecting a string, so you want to use `getElementById("btnaccept");`

As well, to set the text of a button element I believe you will need to use `el.innerText = "Accept";`

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a toggle button for a colapsible panel in the following way:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="changeIcon(this)">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
</button>

<script>
function changeIcon(button) {

    if(button.firstElementChild.getAttribute("class") == "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom")
    {
        button.firstElementChild.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top");
    }
    else
    {
        button.firstElementChild.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom");
    }
}
</script>
```